# JavaFX Drag and Drop on ListView from Explorer

Tags: java, listview, javafx, drag-and-drop, drag

Im trying to implement the ability to add paths of folders in my program by simply dragging the folder from the explorer to my ListView.

The ListView is type String:

In the controller class:

```
    public class Controller {
  @FXML
        protected ListView<String> folderList;
        protected void init(){
        
                folderList.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        System.out.println("test");
        
                        if (event.getGestureSource() != folderList) {
                            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                        }
                        event.consume();
                    }
                });
                
                folderList.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                        boolean succ = false;
                        System.out.println(db);
        
                        try {
                            doFolderAdd(new Folder(db.getString()));
                            succ = true;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        
                        event.setDropCompleted(succ);
                        event.consume();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

My main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException, InterruptedException, WriterException {


        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/ch/makery/address/view/App.fxml"));

        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

        ctrl = loader.getController();
        ctrl.init();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        ctrl.setStage(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Corresponding FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onDragOver="" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4c4c4c;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ch.makery.address.model.Controller">
    <children>
      <ListView id="testList" fx:id="list" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    </children>
</Pane>
```

I cannot even test if my logic of adding paths is working, since none of these Events are ever fired when I drag an item from a windows explorer window onto the list.

What I noticed is, that if I open a FileChooser from my program, and drag an item from there onto the list, the event is indeed fired, however that is the only case. I was not able to find anything about this issue.

On drag, from a explorer window, it only shows me the 'denied/blocked' icon

Comment: Post a [mre]. There are many reasons why this might happen, and without code to test, everyone will just be guessing.

Comment: I added it,  removing my custom cell factory did not change anything as well

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly

Comment: uh? i dont get whats missing

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 latest

Comment: I also tried adding setOnDragOver to my scene, shows the same result

Comment: Same for manually adding a new component with a setOnDragOver listener, and this is not only the case for files and folders from the explorer, but also anything else dragged (text etc)

Comment: @Dahlin Is that true from anywhere? Since you mention the problem is only when the application is executed from Eclipse, can you drag anything from Eclipse to the JavaFX app? Does drag-and-drop work internally to the JavaFX application?

Comment: Yes dragging items from eclipse to the application actually works

Comment: Then that makes [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426119/javafx-drag-and-drop-on-listview-from-explorer/66461539?noredirect=1#comment117500763_66461539) even more likely. Windows 10 prevents drag-and-drop from working when the source and target applications don't have the same permissions. _File Explorer_ is not executed with admin privileges, at least not by default, hence your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the following:

- The problem only occurs when launching the JavaFX application from *Eclipse*.
- You're running *Eclipse* with administrator privileges.
- You can drag things from *Eclipse* to the JavaFX application.

With that information, you're most likely running into the issue described over at [Why doesn't usual Drag&Drop work in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1172989/why-doesnt-usual-dragdrop-work-in-windows-10) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Here's an excerpt from the accepted answer:

> You see a effect of the [User Account Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). [Drag & Drop](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/01/28/q-why-doesnt-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi/) only works for programs that have the same permission level. If you run an application as admin, you can only drag and drop files from applications that also run as admin.
>
> > **User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)**
> >
> > UIPI blocks Windows messages being sent from process with a lower MIC level to one running at a higher MIC level. Drag-and-drop is implemented via Windows messages. Therefore, if you try and drag-and-drop a file from Windows Explorer (medium MIC) to Notepad running elevated (high MIC), the Windows messages are blocked and drag-and-drop doesn’t work.

Since *Eclipse* has administrator privileges so does your JavaFX application. *File Explorer* does not run with administrator privileges, at least [not by default](https://superuser.com/questions/1060456/is-there-any-way-to-run-file-explorer-as-administrator-under-windows-10/1060578#1060578), hence your issue. The solution is to either make *File Explorer* run with administrator privileges, don't run *Eclipse* with said privileges, or to simply "suffer through" this problem during development (or find a way to make sure the JavaFX application doesn't inherit the admin status).

Comment: However, that brings me to another problem...since my program needs to be run as Admin, and the explorer isnt run as admin by default, no user will be able to use the drag and drop feature

Comment: There may be way to do what you want. I'm not an expert in UAC though, so even if there is I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of found a fix.

The described behavior is the case when the program is run from the IDE(Eclipse).

However, after exporting it as a JAR, and trying drag and drop, it does work. I have no clue how to fix this inside of the IDE.

Comment: Are you running Eclipse with administrator privileges?

Comment: yes I am, since this is required by my Registry Reader

Comment: Then I believe you're running into this: https://superuser.com/questions/1172989/why-doesnt-usual-dragdrop-work-in-windows-10